# cannot import a module from scikitlearn

Tags: python, module, scale, scikit-learn

I‘m using `scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)` to pre-process my feature values.

However, when it is run, there's an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StandardScaler'
```

I can successfully import preprocessing from `sklearn` and use its 'scale' method:
`X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X)`.

But `StandardScaler` just doesn't work. Could anybody help? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of `sklearn` is used? `StandardScaler` is introduced in `sklearn` version `0.13`. There is no StadardScaler in [previous release](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.12.X/sklearn/preprocessing.py). You probably need to upgrade you installation.

To check version out try

```
python -c "import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__)"
```

Comment: oh,yeah, mine is the older version. Thanks